TimeoutException with selenium. Why is happening if the element is there and I'm waiting for it to be visible?
I'm trying to make a simple scrape. The idea is simple: it goes to the search's page of an ecommerce, click on product, go to product's page, scrape the information and go back to search's page to click on the next product and so on. But it goes stuck when trying to find the next button for pagination.  Here is the code:

def common_extraction():
    spreadsheet_data = []
    pdf_data = []
    sizes = []
    currency_exchange()  # Assuming this function is already defined
    url_line = "https://www.scottsmenswear.com/searchresults?descriptionfilter=adidas#dcp=1&dppp=60&OrderBy=rank&Filter=1199_4098646%5EJoggers"
    page = 0
    i = 0
    x = 0
    df_spreadsheet = pd.DataFrame(columns=SPREADSHEET_COLUMNS)
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
    driver.get(url_line)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    
    while True:
        page += 1
        
        product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id = 'navlist']/li//a[@class = 'ProductImageList']"))
        )
        
        for index, value in enumerate(product_list):
            product_list = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(
                EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//ul[@id = 'navlist']/li//a[@class = 'ProductImageList']"))
            )
            
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", product_list[index])
            
            image = product_list[index].find_element(By.XPATH, "//img[@class = 'rtimg MainImage img-responsive']").get_attribute("src")
            print(image)
            
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", product_list[index])
            
            i += 1
            print(i)
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.save_screenshot("ecommerce_project/screenshots_products/common_extraction/" + str(i) + ".png")
            product_page = driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(product_page, "html5lib")
            product_code = driver.current_url.split('colcode=', 1)[1]
            brand_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "lblProductBrand"))).text
            model_name = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class ='prodTitle']//span[@id = 'lblProductName']"))).text
            product_name = brand_name + model_name
            print(product_name)
            
            print(product_code)
            price = soup.find("span", id='lblSellingPrice').text
            price = re.sub("£", "", price)
            product_price = float(price)
            print(price)
            
            size_list = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//ul[@id = 'ulSizes']")
            
            if size_list:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", size_list)
                for size in size_list.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[@id = 'liItem']"):
                    product_size = size.text
                    sizes.append(product_size)
                    if "-" in size.text:
                        product_size = size.text.split('-')[0]
                        sizes.append(product_size)
                    elif "(" in size.text:
                        product_size = size.text.split('(')[0]
                        sizes.append(product_size)
            else:
                product_size = ""
                sizes.append(product_size)
            print(sizes)
            print("calculate price:")                
            price_in_reais = calculate_price_in_reais(product_price)  # Function needs to be defined
            selling_price = calculate_selling_price(product_price)    # Function needs to be defined
                
            spreadsheet_data.append({
                #'Photo': image,
                'Code': product_code,
                'Description': product_name,
                'Purchase': price_in_reais,
                'Sale': selling_price,
                'Sizes': sizes
            })
                
            pdf_data.append({
                #'Photo': image,
                'Code': product_code,
                'Description': product_name,
                'Price': product_price
            })
            driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
            driver.back()
            
        try:
            driver.save_screenshot("pagination_screen.png")
            print("Looking for 'Next' button...")
            time.sleep(5)
            next_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'divPagination']//a[@class = 'swipeNextClick NextLink ']"))
            )
        
            if next_button:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", next_button)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", next_button)
                print("clicked")
                x += 1
                print(f"Page {x} processed.")
                time.sleep(5)
            else:
                print("'Next' button not found. Finishing.")
                break
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Timeout waiting for 'Next' button. Finishing.")
            break

    pdf.output('catalog.pdf', "F")
    
    df_spreadsheet = pd.DataFrame(spreadsheet_data)
    df_spreadsheet.to_excel("catalog.xlsx")

it ALWAYS bring me a TimeoutException on this line:
proximo_botao = WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(
                    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id = 'divPagination']//a[@class = 'swipeNextClick NextLink ']"))
                    )

I've tried with visibility and presence, I've putted this long XPATH to avoid any ambiguity, but nothing worked. What is wrong with it?
Trying to avoid timeout exceptions errors.

sort of unusual to have a space at the end of the class attribute there.  Can you include the markup of the link you are trying to target?  It's also odd to have the two "((" there.  Is that a python thing?
